# MySQL - Checking nonexistent records

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to check for existing rows in mysql.

I have a table called "history", in this table I save records of movements in my platform.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| movement_id |     movement             |   product_id    |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  1          |       movement_1         |   5             |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  2          |       movement_2         |   5             |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  3          |       movement_3         |   5             |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  4          |       movement_1         |   6             |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  5          |       movement_3         |   6             |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to get all the `product_id`'s that don't have `movement_2` but does have `movement_3`. In the example above the ID that I would like to return is `6`, but this can be more than one id.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group by product_id` and use a condition in the `having` clause:

```
select product_id
from history
where movement in ('movement_2', 'movement_3')
group by product_id
having 
  sum(movement = 'movement_2') = 0
  and
  sum(movement = 'movement_3') > 0
```

or **in this case only** (because `movement_2 < movement_3`), this would work also:

```
having min(movement) = 'movement_3'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=9e4dc3ff268d38f47fe78b089b73c808).
Results:

```
> | product_id |
> | ---------: |
> |          6 |
```

Comment: What if I don't the exact movement description? I only know what that movement string starts off with. For example, movement_2 always starts with `'Moved to inventory ... more detailed description here'` and movement_3 always starts off with `'Item was received ... more detailed description here'`. I'm guessing I need to change the HAVING filter to use something like this `sum(movement LIKE '%Moved to inventory%') = 0`?

Comment: Exactly. Put the condition, whatever it is, as long as it is a valid boolean expression, inside SUM().